# Sharing Moments in GooglePlus from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-plus

Are there any libraries out there for C# that wrap the process of sharing moments to a user's Google+ account (or to their stream)?  I'm looking for something that simply take your ClientId and ClientSecret, and maybe your apiKey along with the user's id to send some text that the user has decided to share with his/her friends.

If not, but you have an example of creating a WebRequest to accomplish the same thing, that would be much appreciated too!

I've reviewed this landing page: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp

But I'm trying to integrate into an existing MVC5 application that already has the Auth for GooglePlus taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

The correct client to be using for Google APIs is the [Google .NET API Client library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/), available via NuGet. Additional libraries for specific APIs are required if you use more than the core library. For Plus, you need the **Google.Apis.Plus.v1** package.

After you have added it to your projects and have configured an API client, writing app activities is as easy as:

```
    /// <summary>The app activity type for ADD.</summary>
    private const string ADD_ACTIVITY_TYPE = @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

    // Construct your Plus Service, I'll assume a helper for here.
    PlusService plusService = GetPlusService(credentials);
    Moment addMoment = new Moment();
    ItemScope target = new ItemScope()
        {
            Url = ContentUrl
        };
    addMoment.Type = ADD_ACTIVITY_TYPE;
    addMoment.Target = target;

    Moment response = null;
    try
    {
        response = plusService.Moments.Insert(addMoment, "me",
            MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault).Execute();
    }
    catch (System.AggregateException)
    {
        /* Occurs when the server can't be seen by Google. */
    }
    catch (Google.GoogleApiException)
    {
        /* Occurs when the server can't be seen by Google. */
    }
```

How to authenticate a user and authorize your client for access to Google APIs in MVC can be found on this blog: [ASP.NET MVC with OpenID and OAuth](http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-with-google-openid-and-oauth.html).

A final note, app activities require you to specify an app activities pseudo-scope (request_visible_actions) which is easier with the Sign-In button than via the framework. If you are getting 401 errors, this is the most likely culprit.

Comment: So I have added the reference through NuGet for Google APIs Client Library v 1.8.1 with no issue.  However, I must be missing 1 or more references because I cannot resolve the namespace PlusService is in nor can my instance of ReSharper.  Any advice?  Also is the PlusHelper custom or part of Google's API?

Comment: Updated the code to make it a little more clear. The NuGet package you are looking for is Google.Apis.Plus.v1.